# The help tab opened by shift+tab in jupyter notebook doesn't render the docstring of a method/function properly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, docstring

I am trying to read the documentation(docstring) of a function or method using the important shortcut of jupyter notebook **"shift+tab"** but it doesn't render the text properly.
For example, on looking the docstring of `confusion_matrix` function:

[image]

You can see the highlighted part that I am getting those weird text rendered( *math:* ) before actual text. This makes it hard to read the docstring. I want it to render it like the documentation of sklearn like this,
[image]

I feel like some library isn't loaded or downloaded. I am new to using jupyter notebooks, so please be kind :)

PS: I have tried restarting the theme also but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.. math::` is an rst markup.

They have mentioned in the ["under-progress" repo](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2581) that Docstring doesn't support Mathematical notations, as they are written in **[-rst](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/rst/quickref.html) format**.

Frankly, there is no support added for reStructuredText in Jupyter as of now, hence you would have to search ways to manually apply for the support. Check out **[@akaihola's attempt](https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/241#issuecomment-455207852)** on a comparative issue.

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with a different approach. See if it helps you.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
?confusion_matrix
```

run the cell using run button or shift+enter

Comment: It still doesn't render the docstring text correctly